# Dataframe pivot in specific format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Currently I have a dataframe in the following format :

```
ID  Value   Type    Month
1   0.1     B       Jan
2   0.2     A       Jan
1   0.15    A       Feb
2   0.1     B       Feb
```

I am trying to get it to display each column value by month like so:

```
Month Jan            Feb
      Value   Type   Value   Type
ID     
1     0.1     B      0.15    A
2     0.2     A      0.1     B
```

I run the following to pivot the data

```
df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Month', values=['Type', 'Value'])
```

But instead the table comes out like so

```
      Value        Type
      Jan   Feb    Jan   Feb
ID     
1     0.1   0.15   B     A
2     0.2   0.1    A     B
```

Is there any way to get it to come out like I want? Have not been able to find a way to structure the pivot table like I want to. [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe?rq=1) does not appear to address this specific format request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) from your last pivotted `df`.

```
df2.swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[False, False])
```

---

```
Month   Jan        Feb     
      Value Type Value Type
ID                         
1       0.1    B  0.15    A
2       0.2    A   0.1    B
```